# Two functions, One generator

Tags: python

I have two functions which both take iterators as inputs. Is there a way to write a generator which I can supply to both functions as input, which would not require a `reset` or a second pass through?  I want to do one pass over the data, but supply the output to two functions:  Example:

```
def my_generator(data):
    for row in data:
        yield row

gen = my_generator(data)
func1(gen)
func2(gen)
```

I know I could have two different generator instances, or `reset` in between functions, but was wondering if there is a way to avoid doing two passes on the data.  Note that func1/func2 themselves are NOT generators, which would be nice cause I could then have a pipeline.

The point here is to try and avoid a second pass over the data.

Comment: good points to both you guys.  I guess I have a more fundamental issue which is I didn't implement the 2 functions in question.  One function is bulk loading into an rtree, the other is loading into bcolz.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either **cache** generators result into a list, **or** **reset** the generator to pass data into `func2`. The problem is that if one have 2 loops, one needs to iterate over the data twice, so either one loads the data again and create a generator or one caches the entire result.

Solutions like `itertools.tee` will also just create 2 iteratvies, which is basically the same as resetting the generator after first iteration. Of course it is syntactic sugar but it won't change the situation in the background.

If you have big data here, you have to merge `func1` and `func2`.

```
for a in gen:
   f1(a)
   f2(a)
```

In practice it can be a good idea to design code like this, so one has full control over iteration process and is able associate/compose maps and filters using a single iterative.

Answer (score 3):

Python has an amazing catalog of handy functions. You find the ones related to iterators in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee):

```
import itertools

def my_generator(data):
    for row in data:
        yield row

gen = my_generator(data)
gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(gen)
func1(gen1)
func2(gen2)
```

However, this only makes sense if `func1` and `func2` don't consume all the elements, because if they do `itertools.tee()`has to remember all the elements in `gen`until `gen2` is used.

To get around this, use only a few elements at a time. Or change `func1` to call `func2`. Or maybe even change `func1` to be a lazy generator which returns the input and just pipe that into `func2`.

Comment: Itertools is OP's best friend here. He touched upon resetting generators, which would actually be done in the same way as this example. +1

Answer (score 3):

If using threads is an option, the generator may be consumed just once without having to store a possibly unpredictable number of yielded values between calls to the consumers. The following example runs the consumers in lock-step; Python 3.2 or later is needed for this implementation:

```
import threading


def generator():
    for x in range(10):
        print('generating {}'.format(x))
        yield x


def tee(iterable, n=2):
    barrier = threading.Barrier(n)
    state = dict(value=None, stop_iteration=False)

    def repeat():
        while True:
            if barrier.wait() == 0:
                try:
                    state.update(value=next(iterable))
                except StopIteration:
                    state.update(stop_iteration=True)
            barrier.wait()
            if state['stop_iteration']:
                break
            yield state['value']

    return tuple(repeat() for i in range(n))


def func1(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        print('func1 consuming {}'.format(x))


def func2(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        print('func2 consuming {}'.format(x))


gen1, gen2 = tee(generator(), 2)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=func1, args=(gen1,))
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=func2, args=(gen2,))
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit too late, but maybe will be helpful for someone. For simplicity I have added only one ChildClass, but the idea is to have multiple of them:

```
class BaseClass:
    def on_yield(self, value: int):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def summary(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self._aggregated_value = 0
    def on_yield(self, value: int):
        self._aggregated_value += value
    def summary(self):
        print(f"Aggregated value={self._aggregated_value}")

class Generator():
    def my_generator(self, data):
        for row in data:
            yield row
    def calculate(self, generator, classes):
        for index, value in enumerate(generator):
            print(f"index={index}")
            [_class.on_yield(value) for _class in classes]
        [_class.summary() for _class in classes]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    child_classes = [ ChildClass(), ChildClass() ]
    generator = Generator()
    my_generator = generator.my_generator([1, 2, 3])
    generator.calculate(my_generator, child_classes)
```

The output of this is:

```
index=0
index=1
index=2
Aggregated value=6
Aggregated value=6
```